# JS and HTML on a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension and I am having trouble with the popup.js and popup.html. I'm trying to make it cycle text based on the day of the week. However, I can't get my popup.js code to work. I'm not proficient at javascript or html. I use java more but I'm doing a project for my school.

Although I currently have a button, my end goal is just for once the extension in clicked open, it displays the menu. I have no idea how to begin even coding a loop based off day of the week than also formats into html.

popup.html

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="column large-6 medium-6 small-12">
        <h1> Lunch Menu </h1>
        <p> filler filler filler</p>
        <button onclick="main()" id="buttons">Generate</button>
        <div id="text">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

popup.js

```js
function main() {
       var today = new Date();
      weekday = today.getDay();
      showImages = [];
      myText = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', ];
      text = ((document.getElementById) ? document.getElementById("text"));
      text.innerHTML = myText[weekday];
      return text;
      }
```

Comment: Hi Joey welcome to SO. Can you expand what you mean "can't get it to work"? Is this running in the browser or as a chrome extension? Do you get an error?

Comment: See [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](//stackoverflow.com/a/25721457) and [The Chrome extension popup is not working, click events are not handled](//stackoverflow.com/q/17601615) and [Google Chrome / Firefox do not see extension output in console](//stackoverflow.com/a/38920982)

Comment: It says anonymous function. My popup.js is most likely wrong. It's running as an extension.

Comment: My goal is for on a different day of the week, the extension displays different text. I'm using the button right now but in the end I just want text and no button.

Comment: The links I gave fully explain the problem and the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
text = ((document.getElementById) ? document.getElementById("text"));
```

You are using a conditional (ternary) operator but not supplying the second expression. That might be the cause of your issue. I would have just put this information in a comment but I'm new to StackOverflow and don't have enough reputation to add comments.